# Where do CPUID information stores in possessor?

Tags: assembly, x86, cpuid

CPUID is an x86 Assembly instruction to get CPU specs and information, like if hyper-threading is allowed or a virtualization is supported. but does anybody knows, where this information is stored in the processor? is it in micro code?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to know this, other than idle curiosity?  It's stored on the die somewhere, probably in the microcode, actually.

Comment: Instructions that take *dozens* of cycles, like cpuid, are invariably implemented in microcode.  Processor manufacturers treat details like this as proprietary and secret, you can't find out for a fact.

Comment: Thank you Robert and Hans. Furthermore, some functionality of CPU was switched off by manufacturer. so what CPUID will return, contains that switched off functionality or just skipped through?